# OpenNTF ApplicationLayout and GlyphIcons : how to use?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, glyphicons

I'm using the last ExtensionLibrary (v11), theme 'bootstrap3.2.0' and ApplicationLayout control with 'bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration';
I'm trying to use GlyphIcons in ApplicationLinks without success:

Is it possible? Can someone provide an example?

This is part of code I try (no error returned):

```
    <xe:this.configuration>
        <xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration
            productLogo="/abc.gif"
            productLogoHeight="38px"
            titleBarName="#{javascript:sessionScope.ssCurrentApplication}"
            placeBarName="Place Bar"
            footer="false"
            legal="false"
            fixedNavbar="fixed-top"
        >
            <xe:this.bannerApplicationLinks>

                <xe:basicLeafNode
                    label="Safety"
                    submitValue="APPLSafety"
                    styleClass="glyphicon glyphicon-save"
                >
                    <xe:this.selected><![CDATA[#{javascript:isThisApplication("Safety");}]]></xe:this.selected>
                </xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicContainerNode label="Safety">
                    <xe:this.children>
                        <xe:basicLeafNode
                            submitValue="Safety Tool\By Config"
                            label="By Config"
                            styleClass="glyphicon glyphicon-save"
                        >
                            <xe:this.selected><![CDATA[#{javascript:isThisView("Safety Tool\\By Config");}]]></xe:this.selected>
                        </xe:basicLeafNode>
```

Where I use **styleClass="glyphicon glyphicon-save"** is where I try to define it; what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I think this was reported to us before, and there is a limitation in the tree nodes that doesn't allow you to set the style class properly. We have to create an enhancement request to fix that.

However, you can get around it by using jquery that is part of the bootstrap plugin. Here's a code snippet that I am using in the xpages boiler plate application that we're developing for our bluemix stuff. The first part is an onClientLoad event that stuffs the glyphicons into the app layout utility links:

```
<xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
        $(".applayout-utility-links li:nth-child(1) a").prepend("<div style='padding-top:2px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></div>")
        $(".applayout-utility-links li:nth-child(2) a").prepend("<div style='padding-top:2px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></div>")
        $(".applayout-utility-links li:nth-child(3) a").prepend("<div style='padding-top:2px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></div>")
        $(".applayout-utility-links li:nth-child(4) a").prepend("<div style='padding-top:2px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign'></div>")
        $(".applayout-utility-links li:nth-child(5) a").prepend("<div style='padding-top:2px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign'></div>")]]>
    </xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

The other part is defining the links themselves, and all you need to provide is the href property, leave the label blank if you want:

```
<xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
    <xe:basicLeafNode href="dashboard.xsp"></xe:basicLeafNode>
    <xe:basicLeafNode href="todos.xsp"></xe:basicLeafNode>
    <xe:basicLeafNode href="complete.xsp"></xe:basicLeafNode>
    <xe:basicLeafNode href="urgent.xsp"></xe:basicLeafNode>
    <xe:basicLeafNode href="overdue.xsp"></xe:basicLeafNode>
</xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
```

That code should work for application links by just replacing `xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks` above with `xe:this.bannerApplicationLinks`. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks Brian, it works; it can be used also for submenu of ApplicationLinks in this way: $(".applayout-links li:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1) a").prepend("<div style='padding-top:2px;color:red;font-size:40px' class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></div>")
 $(".applayout-links li:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2) a").prepend("<div style='padding-top:2px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></div>")
 $(".applayout-links li:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(3) a").prepend("<div style='padding-top:2px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></div>")
...